# java Set to javaScript Array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java

i am seeking your help regarding this issue, i am trying to convert a java set to a javascript array in my JSP but it doesn't work, here is my code

```
var ci=new Array();
            <%
               Object temp[]=map.keySet().toArray();
            %>
             ci=<%=temp%>;
            for(var i=0; i<ci.size() ;i++){

        }
```

i tried this too

```
    var ci=new Array();
              <% int size=map.keySet().size();
               Object temp[]=map.keySet().toArray(new Object[size]);%>
                ci=<%=temp%>;
            for(var i=0; i<ci.size() ;i++){}
```

the error i get is "unexpected token ; " 
any ideas about the error source or another strategy to convert?

Thank you in advance